# How to make a joystick in flutter where the inner circle doesnt leave the outer circle?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, canvas, view

I am trying to create a joystick in flutter but I am not able to limit the inner circle inside the outer circle in a proper way,is there any suggestion for this?,Also is it possible for the outer circle to set a an image as background ..I have tried restricting it using a range of offsets but I am not sure if that is the right way of doing this .....Here is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: JoyStick(),
  ));
}

class JoyStick extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _JoyStickState createState() => _JoyStickState();
}

class _JoyStickState extends State<JoyStick> {
  Offset offset, smallCircleOffset;
  @override
  void initState() {
    offset = Offset(0, 0);
    smallCircleOffset = offset;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          ),
          CustomPaint(
            painter: Painter(false, this.offset,false),
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: Painter(true, smallCircleOffset,(true)),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onPanEnd: (details){
              setState(() {
                smallCircleOffset = offset;
              });

            },
            onPanUpdate: (details) {
              setState(() {
                RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
                smallCircleOffset = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);

              },
              );

            },

          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Painter extends CustomPainter {
  final bool needsRepaint,isInBoundary;
  final Offset offset;
  Painter(this.needsRepaint, this.offset, this.isInBoundary);
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (needsRepaint && isInBoundary) {
      print("Offset for smaller circle  = $offset with distance squared = ${offset.distanceSquared} \n and distance = ${offset.distance}");
      canvas.drawCircle(this.offset, 50, Paint()..color = Colors.amber);
    } else {
      canvas.drawCircle(this.offset, 200, Paint()..color = Colors.black);

    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return (needsRepaint && isInBoundary)?true:false;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `onPanUpdate()` method, only call `setState` if the offset distance is below 200, like this:

```
            onPanUpdate: (details) {
              if(smallCircleOffset.distance < 200){
                setState(() {
                  RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
                  smallCircleOffset = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
                });
              } 

            },
```

If you want a proper joystick that moves inside the circle after panning outside the inner circle, try using [The Control Pad package](https://pub.dev/packages/control_pad) in Flutter. It provides a joystick and gives lot of options as well.

[image: Taken from package readme]

(Picture taken from README.md of the package)

Comment: If you want an exact replica of how a joystick behaves, use the control pad package. I've added the link to the updated answer.